# Message box show output of command

Tags: shell-script

How do I make a text box that show the output of a command? I'm using bash.
Here's the command i'm using

```
    echo -e $(tput setaf 0) $(tput setab 7) $(watch -n0.1 date %r)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dialog --infobox "$(your command here)" 10 30
```

Comment: Or `zenity` or ... lots of options